# Calling Check Names from plugin

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I was wondering if there is a way to call the Check Names function from my Outlook plugin so i can avoid unresolved names which will not be send. My problem is when a user enters an email address which has not been checked / underlined and it calls my plugin i do not get the address in the TO, or CC box which is a big problem. If i go and press check names. the new email is underlined and will be sent. So trying to find a way to automate this process.
So i am looking for some code example or docs which shows how to call the check names function from an plugin

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use `Recipient.Resolve`. Recipient object can be retrieved either from the `MailItem.Recipients` collection or from `Namespace.CreateRecipient`.

Comment: Is this avail from the java script plugin ?

Comment: No, this is in the Outlook Object Model only. I re-tagged your question appropriately.

Comment: In a JS based addin, you can try to use EWS  through mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services) and use the ResolveNames operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/resolvenames-operation)

Comment: I don’t think ews is an option for Microsoft hosted office 365 exchange

Comment: Of course it is, even though not all EWS operations are supported. Did you look at the link in my comment?